# How to use json_query with integer

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2, json-query

Hello Developer Community!

I'm currently working on developing some Ansible playbooks to manage Citrix NetScaler configuration and would like to ask for some help about the following. I have the following data structure defined in a variable file named  **nsadc_config_file_textfsm_nsadc_vlan_binding_parsed**

```
[
    {
        "bind_vlan_NotParsed": "",
        "bind_vlan_id": "1042",
        "bind_vlan_ifnum": "",
        "bind_vlan_ipaddress": "10.162.5.120",
        "bind_vlan_netmask": "255.255.255.128",
        "bind_vlan_ownergroup": "",
        "bind_vlan_tagged": "",
        "bind_vlan_td": ""
    },
    {
        "bind_vlan_NotParsed": "",
        "bind_vlan_id": "1050",
        "bind_vlan_ifnum": "",
        "bind_vlan_ipaddress": "10.162.5.250",
        "bind_vlan_netmask": "255.255.255.128",
        "bind_vlan_ownergroup": "",
        "bind_vlan_tagged": "",
        "bind_vlan_td": ""
    }
]
```

I would like to query this JSON structure with json_query in a Jinja file using a loop to get the record for a specific VLAN ID:

```
{% if (nsadc_config_file_textfsm_nsadc_vlan_binding_parsed | json_query('[?bind_vlan_id == `' + item_0.add_vlan_id + '`]')) %}
```

But unfortunately, the query does not work, I always get an empty result. Both variables `bind_vlan_id` and `add_vlan_id` are integer, but according to my understanding, JSON structure contains string key:value by default. I believe, this could be the cause of the issue: integer vs string. I have already tried a lot of scenarios, but with no luck.

```
 - json_query('[?bind_vlan_id == `' + item_0.add_vlan_id + '`]')
 - json_query('[?bind_vlan_id == `' + item_0.add_vlan_id | string + '`]')
 - json_query('[?bind_vlan_id == item_0.add_vlan_id]')
 - json_query('[?bind_vlan_id == item_0.add_vlan_id | string]')
 - json_query('[?bind_vlan_id == `item_0.add_vlan_id`]')
 - json_query('[?bind_vlan_id == ''item_0.add_vlan_id'']')
```

Could anyone please point me to the right direction, how json_query should work in case of integer value as the condition? Thank You very much in advance!

Comment: See [mre]. Try to minimize the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given simplified data for testing

```yaml
    nsadc:
      - id: "1042"
        ipaddress: "10.162.5.120"
      - id: "1050"
        ipaddress: "10.162.5.250"
```

---

Q: **"*Loop to get the record for a specific ID.*"**

A: Put the query into a variable. This will simplify the quoting and escaping. For example

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ nsadc|json_query(query) }}"
  loop: ["1042", "1050", "9999"]
  vars:
    query: "[?id == '{{ item }}']"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=1042) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "id": "1042",
            "ipaddress": "10.162.5.120"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=1050) => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "id": "1050",
            "ipaddress": "10.162.5.250"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=9999) => {
    "msg": []
}
```

---

- The attribute *id* is not an integer

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ nsadc.0.id|type_debug }}"
```

gives

```yaml
    "msg": "AnsibleUnicode"
```

An integer is declared without quotes. For example

```yaml
        id: 1042
```

would give

```yaml
    "msg": "int"
```

---

Q: **"*Jinja template error*"**

```yaml
{% set query = '[?id == '{{ item_0.id }}']' %}
```

A: If you insist on creating the query in Jinja then the string must be concatenated. For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          {% set query = "[?id == '" ~ item_0.id ~ "']" %}
          {{ nsadc|json_query(query) }}
      vars:
        item_0:
          id: "1042"
```

gives

```yaml
    "msg": " [{'id': '1042', 'ipaddress': '10.162.5.120'}]"
```

Comment: Dear Vladimir! 
Many thanks for Your prompt answer. I have tried placing the item between double curly braces, but when I try to run it, I'm still getting error message: template error while templating string: expected token 'end of statement block', got '{'.

Is the mentioned method valid also when using json_query in a Jinja file?

{% set query = '[?bind_vlan_id == '{{ item_0.add_vlan_id }}']' %}
{% if (nsadc_config_file_textfsm_nsadc_vlan_binding_parsed | json_query(query)) %}

Comment: You're welcome. I've added a Jinja example. Open new question if you have other issues.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank You very much, Vladimir!